# Полный путь к точке выброса исключения

Tags: java, стек

Как избавиться от "**... 1 more**" и увидеть полный стек вызовов, приведших к выбросу исключения, если результатом выводится только это:

```
// other output data
myPack.DynamicFieldsException
    at myPack.DynamicFields.setField(DynamicFields.java:69)
    at myPack.DynamicFields.main(DynamicFields.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myPack.DynamicFields.setField(DynamicFields.java:70)
    ... 1 more
```

Просьба в ответе показать конкретный пример, т.е.

```
catch (MyException e) { ??? }
```

Какой код следует использовать вместо "???" чтобы получить желаемый результат (полный вывод стека) ?

Сейчас используется:

```
catch (MyException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Такой вариант:

```
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        for (StackTraceElement l : e.getStackTrace())
            System.out.println(l);
}
```

не показывает причину, заранее заданную как `new Exception(new Exception());` или как `new MyException().initCause(new MyException());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот способ вывода информации об исключении, является способом по умолчанию. Вот так это выглядит в коде

```
if (framesInCommon != 0)
    s.println(prefix + "\t... " + framesInCommon + " more");
```

Но вы всегда можете перехватить исключение и вывести его в нужном вам формате. Метод `getStackTrace` вернет вам массив типа `StackTraceElement`. В нем вы найдете всю необходимую информацию о стеке.

```
try {
    throw new Exception(new NullPointerException());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Throwable cause = ex;
    while (cause != null) {
        for(StackTraceElement element: cause.getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
        cause = cause.getCause();
        if(cause != null) {
            System.out.println("Caused by " + cause);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поправьте только `System.out.println("Caused by " + cause.getMessage());` на `System.out.println("Caused by " + cause);` прошу. Это будет ближе к стандартному выводу, ибо там именно так.